# How to point wildcard subdomain to matching ec2 instance with tag name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I have a use case where I need to create/delete ec2 instances (~30 instances). To access those instances I need to set up a subdomain but creating 30 subdomains and pointing each to their respective instance doesn't seem right to me considering I may add more or delete some of the instances.

Is there any way I can add the wildcard subdomain (*.example.com) and point to the respective instance with the matching tag-name/subdomain?

For example: If I hit **server-01**.example.com it should point to the instance with the tag name: **server-01**.